# Riddle - what is the word? I am a similar of the answer

Tags: riddle, word, anagram

What is the answer and why?

> I am a similar of the answer,
>
> A jumbled flower atom,
>
> plus 14, I am a muddled, missing alliance,
>
> My answer is an answer, a mix.

What word am I?

Comment: Haven't you heard? About the bird?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lm6Qh2-CI58

Comment: alright people I have added another clue in the TAGS

Comment: You say both "I" and "the answer" here, which indicates two separate things - which are you looking for?

Comment: @question_asker basically I am looking for a single word. But to make it a riddle I imagined 'I' am the word

Comment: OK, so when you say "I am [a] similar [of] the answer", and then later say "my answer[...]", that makes it sound like *you* and *the answer* are still two different things

Comment: @question_asker Manshu just got it but not with the clues. Everyone-think of the NEW TAG I just added. It will help solve the riddle

Comment: There are two anagrams-him who gets them gets the accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building off of manshu's answer, the answer is

> solution

I am a similar of the answer:

> 'solution' and 'answer' are synonyms

A jumbled flower atom:

> 'solution' is an anagram of 'lotus ion'
>
>  A lotus is a flower, and an ion is a charged atom

plus 14, I am a muddled, missing alliance,:

> 'solution' with another N (14th letter of the alphabet) is an anagram of 'lost union'

My answer is an answer, a mix.

> A solution is a mixture comprised of a solute and a solvent

Comment: Congratulations @Will you did it!

Comment: Just for fun - try and add what an ion is in your answer, some might not know...

Comment: holy crud, nice work

Comment: I was looking at my own answer and BAMM, the question is answered by Will...great job.

Comment: Very well done indeed

Comment: Just saying, if you upvote this you should also upvote manshu's answer! :)

Comment: I have, but unfortunately can't accept, sorry

Comment: how did you find the anagrams?

Comment: @manshu - The first one just kinda hit me, then for the second one I thought of (short) synonyms, came up with a near anagram, and realized the letter I was missing fit the clue.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is

> Carbon

I am a similar of the answer

> Carbon copy - identical

A jumbled flower atom

> It can bind to anything and can form long chains called polymers. Also The actual location of electrons in a carbon atom cannot be determined orbiting the nucleus .

plus 14, I am a muddled, missing alliance,

> I think this is the Carbon-14 used for carbon dating. Carbon-14 is not stable unlike Carbon-12 and has radioactive decay. Also carbon-14, which makes up a minuscule amount of overall carbon in the universe. Carbon-12 (99%) and Carbon-13 (1%)

My answer is an answer, a mix.

> Can bind with other elements and is found in many different compounds and almost everything.

Comment: Closer but it's even more subtle. I'll add another clue to help people

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is:

> sixteen

I am a similar of the answer,

> I think this refers to 't', the sixteenth consonant in the alphabet.

A jumbled flower atom,

> An atom of flower could be 'ow', jumbled gives 'wo' and added to 't' gives 'two'

plus 14,

> 2 + 14 = 16

I am a muddled, missing alliance,

> 'I am a' could refer to 'existence', muddled gives 'sixteenec' and without alliance (ec, european community) gives 'sixteen'.

My answer is an answer, a mix.

> a mix could refer to a combination of all the lower case a that appear in the question (including lines above and below) which is sixteen.

Obviously, a bit convoluted but let me know if I'm anywhere near.

Comment: Nice try @Stephen but I am afraid your nowhere near. Welcome to the site. I like your reasoning though.

Answer (score 2):

i think the answer is

> Solution

I am a similar of the answer,

> Answer is the synonym  of solution

A jumbled flower atom,

> In chemistry we take special care of the random atoms used in making a solution

plus 14, I am a muddled, missing alliance,

> Not sure about this. Maybe this part of the riddle is 'missing alliance'.

My answer is an answer, a mix.

> Solution is a mixture of chemicals.

Comment: U GOT IT! Not with the clues though. (Think of the anagram tag)

Comment: I'll accept when you get the clues right

Comment: Oh, now that you say this is the solution, that's a cute anagram.

Comment: Thanks @Will, can you work I out the two anagrams though?

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil WOW, that second one is clever.

Comment: :) If you can get the other one you can get the accept